# Render d3 SVG graph using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

[Here is my current fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/b3jJ5/2/).

I'm using the stock d3 example taken from [this page](http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729).  I'm trying to modify it so that I can apply my custom CSS as well as some Knockout Bindings.  I have tried replacing the append("svg:text") with "foreignObject" and "tspan", as recommended in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/d2ceKITfTx0).  It showed up in the DOM under the "g" element, but did not show up properly in the browser.

I'm currently trying to just remove the .append statements for the circle and the text and step through each "g" element and apply custom classes using addClass, as below, but it doesn't add them at all.

```
anchorNode.each(function (i, value) {
    $(this).addClass('entity').addClass('relNode');
})
```

How can I utilize custom HTML/CSS with the d3 library?  Specifically, this example.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Do you want to have a force directed layout with HTML elements instead of SVG, or do you want to apply special styling to the SVG elements?

Comment: Preferably the first, but the second if possible :)

Comment: The first isn't really possible because you wouldn't be able to draw the links. For the second, you can use CSS for SVG in the same way as you would use it for HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVG is not a free for all. Each element has permitted children as well as parents. [***tspan***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan) for example goes within a svg *text* element. When it comes to the group element, here are permitted elements within the [***g***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) SVG element. To use the tspan, you must embed it within text as per this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw74p/)

When it comes to the [***foreignObject***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject), you can use it to embed foreign xml derivitives such as xhtml IF the user-agent (browser) supports it. It's often used with switch statement, where the switch statement will test the **requiredExtensions** attribute for first true and waterfall down as mentioned in the documentation I linked you to. Here's a 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zn9fH/) that demonstrates this depending on the support of your user-agent.

```
var switches = anchorNode.append("svg:switch")
switches.append("svg:foreignObject")
  .attr("requiredExtensions", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
  .append("body").attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
  .append("p").text(function(d, i) {
    return "a la foreignObject" + (i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.label) 
  }).style("fill", "#555").style("font-family", "Arial").style("font-size", 12);

switches.append("svg:text").append("svg:tspan").text(function(d, i) {
  return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.label
}).style("fill", "#555").style("font-family", "Arial").style("font-size", 12);
```

It's difficult to suggest a solution, without knowing exactly what it is you want to achieve, but hope this helps clarify the issue a bit.

Comment: I really just wanted to be able to apply CSS to each "node".  However given the comments above and your answer I have decided to go a completely different direction.  That being said, this answer is very detailed so I will mark it as accepted.  Thank you.

Comment: @ScottBeeson You can still apply your CSS to the __text__ elements. You can give it a .attr("id", "yourID") and/or .attr("class", "yourCSSClass") and write css rules in your stylesheet. Of you can add your styling declarations inline as you've noticed with the .style("prop", "value"). There are differences to the styling of SVG elements obviously, but same results can be achieved for the most part. Positioning will be done through x, y, dx, dy attributes, color is fill, etc.